# SQL last 6 months visits

Tags: sql, aggregates

Purpose of the report: Identify patients who did not have dental cleanings in the last 6 months

What would be the best approach to write a sql script?

Patients table

| patient_id | patient_name |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | Jason Strong |
| 22 | Ryan Smith |
| 33 | Casey Hammer |

Visits table

| v_id | patient_id | reason_visit | date_of_visit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | medical | 01/01/2021 |
| 2 | 22 | dental cleaning | 11/10/2020 |
| 3 | 22 | annual | 01/01/2021 |
| 4 | 11 | dental cleaning | 5/10/2021 |
| 5 | 11 | annual | 5/1/2021 |

Expected

| patient_id | patient_name |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | Ryan Smith |
| 33 | Casey Hammer |

Casey is on the list because she is not in the visits table meaning she never received a cleaning from our office.

Ryan Smith is on the list because it is time for his cleaning.

I was also thinking what if the patient did not have an appointment in the last 6 months but had an future appointment for dental cleaning. I would want to exclude that.

Comment: tag your database as well

Comment: would be helpful to share how the code you have tried to solve it for some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in postgresql:

```
select * from Patients p
where not exists (
    select 1 from Visits v
    where v.patient_id = p.patient_id
    and reason_visit = 'dental cleaning'
    and date_of_visit < now() - interval '6 month'
)
```

in sql server replace `now() - interval '6 month'` with `dateadd(month, -6,getdate())`

in mysql `date_add(now(), interval -6 month)`

Comment: author should post some effort on their attempt to solve imo